# How to link pages in Ionic 1.4 to get the controller of the new page launched?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So, I am working with Ionic 1.4, currently working in a Page that contents various messages with their own title and I want to send the ID I got from a get request to a new page. Already managed to send it properly with the ng-click direct. The major problem is that, when I redirect to my new page (The content page) seems the controller of this page is not being launched. I've tried to even put an Alert message, but it doesn't seems to work. However, if I access directly to the Page url, the controller is working. So I do think I am not linking it properly. For linking it I'm using the ui-sref method as you can see below.

```
    <ion-item ng-repeat="notice in notices" ng-click="sendMessageId(notice.id)" class="item-icon-right positive" id="notices-list-item18" ui-sref="tabsController.noticeContent()">{{notice.subject}}
      <span class="item-note" am-time-ago="notice.sendingDate"></span>
      <i ng-show="notice.attachment" class="icon ion-android-attach"></i>
      <ion-option-button class="button-royal">Importante</ion-option-button>
    </ion-item>
```

Any clue of how I can fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show us how do you change page? How your states are defined? Moreover, by default, controllers are cached, that means that once created, it is re-used if it is the same. Maybe your problem comes from that point.

Comment: Wow I'm feeling pretty stupid now, sorry for disturbing. Indeed the problem it was because the controller was being cached... Refreshed the server and the problem was fixed. Sorry my dear friend :( I'm quite newbie on this framework